# vb asp.net session variable not working?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic, controls, session-variables

I just want to control which button user clicked, so I use Session Variable to store that data because I have to create all dynamic control in the `Page_Load` *(to allow event handler work properly)*. The problem is this Session Variable is not work at the first time I clicked but only the second time.

Here is my code:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
                'For the first time I want this session variable to be false because Image Button is not yet click
                Me.Session("ImageClick") = False
            End If
            If Me.Session("ImageClick") Then
                'Then after Button Image is clicked I try to add Dynamic control to a div
                AddPreviewTable(0)
                CreateButtomButton(Me.Session("totalPage"))
                Debug.WriteLine(Me.Session("totalPage"))
                Me.Session("ImageClick") = False
            End If
    End sub
```

The problem is I have to click on `ButtonImage` two times to turn `Me.Session("ImageClick")` to True.

Comment: can you show ButtonImage click event code?

Comment: 'Protected Sub btnImage_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnImage.ServerClick
        Me.Session("ImageClick") = True
    End Sub'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` block is incorrect.  You need to cast your session object into a `bool`:

```
If (Session("ImageClick") Is Not Nothing And CBool(Me.Session("ImageClick"))) Then
    'Do your stuff.
End If
```

Comment: I'm very new to asp.net and I'm also using VB.Net can you give me a sample using vb.net? Thank you very much for answer.

Comment: Sorry I overlooked you were using VB.NET.